# Is there a way to make this more clean looking?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, if-statement

How do I improve on this code?
I can't seem to find any better looking code or more readable.

`If anyone knows how to make this more clean please let me know.`

Any tips on how to do it in the future are well appreciated.

```
public IActionResult Opdracht4_5(int score)
{
    var result = "";

    if (score == 100 && score >= 97)
    {
        result = "A+";
    } else if (score <= 96 && score >= 93)
    {
        result = "A";
    } else if (score <= 92 && score >= 90)
    {
        result = "A-";
    } else if (score <= 89 && score >= 87)
    {
        result = "B+";
    } else if (score <= 86 && score >= 83)
    {
        result = "B";
    } else if (score <= 82 && score >= 80)
    {
        result = "B-";
    } else if (score <= 79 && score >= 77)
    {
        result = "C+";
    } else if (score <= 76 && score >= 73)
    {
        result = "C";
    } else if (score <= 72 && score >= 70)
    {
        result = "C-";
    } else if (score <= 69 && score >= 67)
    {
        result = "D+";
    } else if (score <= 66 && score >= 63)
    {
        result = "D";
    } else if (score <= 62 && score >= 60)
    {
        result = "D-";
    } else if (score < 60)
    {
        result = "F";
    }
    
    ViewBag.Output = result;

    
    return View();
}
```

ViewBag.Output = result : Returns the result message to the front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has fixed my issue.

```
public IActionResult Opdracht4_5(int score)
        {
            
            var result = "";
            result = score is 100 and >= 97 ? "A+" :
                score is <= 96 and >= 93 ? "A" :
                score is <= 92 and >= 90 ? "A-" :
                score is <= 89 and >= 87 ? "B+" :
                score is <= 86 and >= 83 ? "B" :
                score is <= 82 and >= 80 ? "B-" :
                score is <= 79 and >= 77 ? "C+" :
                score is <= 76 and >= 73 ? "C" :
                score is <= 72 and >= 70 ? "C-" :
                score is <= 69 and >= 67 ? "D+" :
                score is <= 66 and >= 63 ? "D" :
                score is <= 62 and >= 60 ? "D-" :
                score < 60 ? "F" : result;

            ViewBag.Output = result;
            
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) for example.

```
var result = score switch
{
    100 and >= 97 => "A+",
    <= 96 and >= 93 => "A",
    <= 92 and >= 90 => "A-",
    <= 89 and >= 87 => "B+",
    <= 86 and >= 83 => "B",
    <= 82 and >= 80 => "B-",
    <= 79 and >= 77 => "C+",
    <= 76 and >= 73 => "C",
    <= 72 and >= 70 => "C-",
    <= 69 and >= 67 => "D+",
    <= 66 and >= 63 => "D",
    <= 62 and >= 60 => "D-",
    < 60 => "F",
    _ => ""
};
```

Comment: This code gives an error at the ``switch`` and ``result`` statement. But it looks very good

Comment: It is a C# 8 feature, what dotnet version you are using?

Comment: I have to use the current version of dotnet I can't change the version.

Comment: Thank you for bringing me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

This task can be accomplished much much more effective.
Just check this code:

```
public class GradeCalculator
{
    private static readonly int[] _scores = new int[] { 59, 62, 66, 69, 72, 76, 79, 82, 86, 89, 92, 96 };
    private static readonly string[] _grades = new string[] { "F", "D-", "D", "D+", "C-", "C", "C+", "B-", "B", "B+", "A-", "A", "A+" };

    public string GetGrade(int score)
    {
        int pos = Array.BinarySearch(_scores, score);
        return _grades[pos < 0 ? ~pos : pos];
    }

    public IActionResult Opdracht4_5(int score)
    {
        ViewBag.Output = GetGrade(score);

        return View();
    }
}
```

The `_scores` array contains the maximum score to get specific grade.
The `_grades` array contains grades and have one element more than `_scores` array. Its crucial for the `_scores` array to be sorted ascending, because of how binary search algorithm works. And finally, this approach only makes at most four comparisons to find the right grade.